# How to have changes in ~/.byobu/.tmux.conf take effect without restarting byobu

Tags: linux, bash, shell, byobu

I want to change my default shell in byobu without restarting it.
However, when I modify lines in ~/.byobu/.tmux.conf to do this:

from:

```
set -g default-shell /usr/bin/fish
set -g default-command /usr/bin/fish
```

to:

```
set -g default-shell /usr/bin/zsh
set -g default-command /usr/bin/zsh
```

New windows and sessions still start with the fish prompt.
I am not sure what else to try besides close out of all of the byobu sessions, but this is undesirable because processes are running which I do not want to kill.

How can I change my default shell in byobu, and can I do it without closing all byobu sessions/windows?

Comment: Use the tmux command line to run the appropriate `set` command yourself?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just press <kbd>F5</kbd> to refresh [Byobu](http://byobu.co)!

*Full disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*

Comment: Thank you!  I knew it was something simple, I couldn't find any documentation on the various other questions related to this on how to refresh.

Comment: @Dustin Kirkland - Where do I put my `.tmux.conf` to get it to work with byobu? Is it possible to disable `ctrl+a` behavior in byobu? Apologies for the `@` this is driving me nuts

Comment: @Dustin Kirkland, how can we reload it on a system where F5 is bind to some other program?

Comment: @ScottSkiles `~/.byobu/.tmux.conf` works